# How did I arrive at a logical contradiction?

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs, paradoxes

Assume we've defined a solid cylinder $ x^2+y^2\leq 2y$ 
It follows that $ x^2+(y-1)^2 \leq 1$. We have a solid cylinder of radius one. 
Now let $ y-1$ = $ \sin(\theta) $. Would it be a contradiction to say: by hypothesis, $ x^2+y^2 \leq 2\sin(\theta)+2$ because we can plug in our new y-value from $y-1=\sin(\theta)$? It naively seems valid to say  $ x^2+y^2 \leq 2\sin(\theta)+2$ but we arrive at a contradiction because the cylinder has a radius of 1 and $2\sin(\theta)+2 \geq 1$ =radius of cylinder. I don't know what mistake I made to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: There is no logical contradiction. First, the cilinder is centered on the axis $(0,1,t)$ and not on $(0,0,t)$, so $x^2 + y^2$ need not be less than or equal to one. Also, $2 \sin(\theta) + 2$ is not necessarily greater than $1$.

Comment: But for the original solid cylinder theta ranged from $ 0$  to $2*\pi$. In the next one, $ x^2+(y-1)^2$ , theta still ranged from zero to $2\pi$. In the case where we plugged in and had $ x^2+y^2 \leq 2sin(\theta)+2$ , it must be the case that theta is restricted and cannot assume everyvalue from 0 to 2$\pi$ so our theta symbo needs to be changed throughout to prevent abuse of notation.

Comment: Wait. But you defined $\theta$ to be $\arcsin(y - 1)$. This has nothing to do with the $\theta$ from spherical or cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: $\theta$ is a function of $y$. You could write $\theta(y)$ if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cylinder base (the circle in the $xy$ plane) has a center in $(x,y)=(0,1)$ and just touches the $x$-axis. Thus, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which is the distance *from the origin*, does vary from $0$ (the bottom) to $2$ (the top), i.e. $x^2+y^2$ varies from $0$ to $4$.

Comment: so our radius is 2 of the cylinder and the radius is not 1?

Comment: No, the radius is 1, but $x^2+y^2$ is not (the square of) the radius, it is (the square of) *the distance from the origin (0,0)*, which for you is *not* the centre. Your centre is at (0,1) and the circle goes through (0,0).

Comment: Only when the circle is *centered* in (0,0), the points on it satisfy $x^2+y^2=r^2$. If the centre is in (p,q), then $(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=r^2$, and $x^2+y^2$ varies as the points on the circle come closer and further from the origin (0,0).

Comment: I guess somewhere, sometime, you remembered that "$x^2+y^2$ is the square of the radius"... But it is not. (Actually, it can be, but only if the centre of the circle is precisely in $(0,0)$.) Hope this helps.